# Bootstrap Carousel slides to change after menu closes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, nav

I have created a nav menu that controls the slides of the carousel (bootstrap).

I managed to make it work perfectly. When i press a menu button the slides change and the menu slides back in.

However the problem is that it's doing the actions in the same time and it looks strange.

I would like that the carousel slides change just after the menu was sliding back in.

How can i make it? Maybe with a jquery script?

Thanks.

Comment: Code please.. How about recreating on [bootply](http://bootply.com)?

Comment: Without seeing your js code so just a suggestion...could you not add a jQuery .delay() method  or a timer?

Comment: yes i was already thinking about something like this... that the slides change after 2 seconds, after the menu closed... thing is i dont know how to do it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for requires that the carousel does not slide until your collapse element has finished hiding. I do not recommend using timer or a delay - instead, make use of bootstrap events to coordinate the hiding and animation of your bootstrap elements.

In your carousel's 'slide.bs.carousel' event handler (check events section [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)) call the eventObject's preventDefault so that no slide takes place.

In your collapse element's 'hidden.bs.collapse' event handler (check events section [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)) call $('#carousel').carousel(number) where number is the slide index corresponding to your menu.

The code might look something like this -

```
var shouldSlide = false;
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    if (shouldSlide === false) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
});

$('#collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    shouldSlide = true;
    $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel(3)
});
```

Ofcourse, the code above is not a complete working example - you'll need to coordinate between the two event handlers to make sure everything works as expected. Hope this helps.

Comment: i've tried to modify the code you gave me: var shouldSlide = false;
$('#carousel-content').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    if (shouldSlide === false) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
});

$('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    shouldSlide = true;
    $('#carousel-content').carousel(3)
}); but the slides still change in the same time with the hiding of the menu...

Comment: I've created a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lbaW5SGyAA#) that uses the two events mentioned in my answer. Its pretty basic but it works the way you want it to.

Comment: i just realized now... when i click on any button from the menu the carousel slides NEXT slide... and not brings up the slide that i want... how can i correct it?

Comment: are you calling $(element).carousel('next')? if so you should instead call $(element).carousel(number) where number is the zero based index of the slide.

Comment: i tried now to put a number (3), but it just slides to slide number 3, any button i would press...also when i just close the menu using the menu button...

Comment: you need to get the 'number' variable dynamically and then pass it to the carousel method. You fetch the number from the data-slide-to attribute. So when your menu is clicked, fetch its data-slide-to attribute value and store it in a variable. Pass that variable to the carousel number in the 'slide.bs.carousel' event.

Comment: ok sounds quite complicated...:) can you please help me also with this one?:) maybe work the bootply code on the link i send previously

Comment: its not that complicated really - its all about coordinating your events :) I've updated the bootply. Please check.

Comment: i've forked the bootply - you can access it here http://www.bootply.com/d3lg0joqtp. I'm afraid that's all the help I can provide.